# What is 'arr' in this TypeError: save() missing 1 required positional argument: 'arr'

Tags: python

```
np.save(res_folder +'/{}_{}_{}_{}_{}.npy'.format(i_model, i_method, i_rep, 
y_pred, scores[i_model, i_method, i_rep, len(Lidx)]))
```

I have this error. I don't if I'm doing it right.. can someone tell me how to do it properly.. and according [np.save()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.save.html) I don't understand how arr should look like. should look for an array in the code or what?. please help 
arr : array_like
Array data to be saved.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're passing your data to be saved to the `str.format` call to produce the file name, rather than to `np.save` itself. Just move one closing parenthesis over a bit:

```
np.save(res_folder +'/{}_{}_{}_{}_{}.npy'.format(i_model, i_method, i_rep, y_pred),
                                                                  #    this one  ^
        scores[i_model, i_method, i_rep, len(Lidx)])
                                       # was here  ^
```